# How do I return specific values in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to return specific values from an search that throws back a lot of information. The line which is causing me problems is this:

```
    results = results.map((res) =>      res[0].tracks.items[10]);
```

I think it is the res[0] part as the error reads:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'tracks' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'tracks' of undefined
at results.map (http://127.0.0.1:60990/script.js:15:59)
at Array.map (native)
at Object.$.when.then.results (http://127.0.0.1:60990/script.js:15:35)
at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

I have used .tracks.items because the search throws back an array which is located within tracks and has a certain number of items - I want to return the first 10 items which is why I have placed the number 10 there.

Any ideas as to why it can't read res?

Bit more code context:

```
const app = {};

app.apiUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';
//Allow the user to enter names

app.events = function() {
    $("form .submit-btn").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let tracks = $('#itrack').val();
    tracks = tracks.split(',');
    let searcht = tracks.map(trackName => app.searchTrack(trackName));

    $.when(...searcht)
        .then((...results)=>{
            results = results.map((res) =>      res[0].tracks.items[1]);
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: So what is `res`?

Comment: @zerkms I'm new to javascript but I believe it is creating a value to allow me to map values to results?

Comment: .then((...results)=>{  console.log(results.slice(0,10));}) is this what you want to get?

Comment: it means `res` doesn't return an array of object with a property of `tracks` how your data returned is structured?

Comment: So, `console.log` it, if you don't know what it is?

Comment: @wostex why have you put console.log along with the results? the console.log is just being used to log the value of results - it appears that my value of results is wrong

Comment: "why have you put console.log along with the results?" --- so that you stopped guessing and finally checked what data you have?

Comment: @zerkms I have just console logged the value results after using this stripped back code `results = results.map((res) =>      res[0]);` and res[0] is returning an undefined value - might be why things are not working - any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: What is in `res`? Why do you think it's an array with at least one element?

Comment: @zerkms I am just creating res to pass a value through, it could be called anything

Comment: Any reason why you avoid answering my questions? Why do you think that element is an array with at least one element, so that you could `res[0]` it?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know the answer to it, I'm new to javascript programming and so have told you what I think its doing

Comment: Ok, 10 minutes ago you were suggested `console.log`. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @zerkms yeah I've tried it and it returns an object for first position in array list, success statement for 2nd and object for 3rd and last position

Comment: So what is `res`?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know, I thought it was a value to pass values through to results

Comment: `console.log` it, if you don't know.

Comment: @JonathanChappell let me step in, hehe I think you are very confused or are you trying not to post the return data? you said `I've tried it and it returns an object`. so what is that **OBJECT** look like? show us?

Comment: @Roljhon this is the data I get back when I use `results = results.map((res) => res[0]);` [undefined, "s", undefined] 0: undefined 1:"s" 2:undefined length:3      However, when I don't have that in there and just have the `.when` and .`then` statements I get: [object, "success", object] 0:object > this contains tracks:object > this contains items:array(3) the items in this array are spotify track data

Comment: @zerkms so continuing from above comment I believe that by using `results = results.map((res) =>      res[0].tracks.items[1]);` I am trying to choose a specific part of the array listed in my last comment

Comment: "of the array listed" --- why do you think it's an array?

Comment: @zerkms because it is a string of three results split by commas - what do you think it is?

Comment: Well, `results` is an array. But its items are not. `results` second item is a string. But you still do `[0]` over a string, and get its first character `s`. In programming it is important to understand every line of code you write and be able to explain every result you get back, not just type random characters on your keyboard and expect it to work automagically.

Comment: "some of its items are" --- none of them are: `[object, "success", object]`. **NONE** of the elements is an array. One is an object, one is a string, another is an object. Just get through your code and check **EVERY** variable has the value exactly as you expect. And I would highly suggest you to not use `.map` until you finally understand what you need, and use simple `for` instead.

Comment: @zerkms okay yes I see which part we are talking about now... I have been misnaming it - do you have any ideas as to why it can't read the object as an object when I use `results = results.map((res) =>      res[0]` ?

Comment: You cannot get `res[0]` because `res` is not an array. It's either an object or a string.

Comment: @zerkms so what would I use to denote I wish to get the first item in that array list - i.e object

Comment: `results[0]`? As I mentioned - don't use functions you don't understand (like `.map()`)

Comment: `.map` is complicated. If you don't know JS basics - you don't even try to touch, until you're completely comfortable with all the types JS has and basic control structures like `if` and `for`.

Comment: @wostex yes that returns what I want to get

Comment: @JonathanChappell ok, now if you show response format (i.e. 'results' example) in your question, and desired final output, someone could help you with actual final solution.

Comment: @wostex If you look a few comments above there is the results output - its appearing as objects, however I'm expecting to deal with a string which is why it may not be working? Any ideas why I'm returning an object and not a string - I've used `tracks = tracks.split(',');` in order to try and make a string

Comment: @JonathanChappell do JSON.stringify(results.slice(0,10), null, 2) into your console, copy it and add it to your question. One look worth many words.

Comment: @wostex so like this? `app.events = function() {
    $("form .submit-btn").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let tracks = $('input[type=search]').val();
        tracks = tracks.split(',');
        let searcht = tracks.map(trackName => app.searchTrack(trackName));
        
       
        $.when(...searcht)
            .then((...results)=>{
            results = results.map((res) =>      res[0].tracks);
              JSON.stringify(results.slice(0,10), null, 2);
        });` if so, it still throws back a cannot read property tracks and doesn't print more

Comment: @JonathanChappell can you do just .then((...results)=>{JSON.stringify(results.slice(0,10), null, 2)}) ... and add output INTO YOUR QUESTION above?

Comment: @wostex `[Object, "success", Object]                                                             0
:
Object
tracks
:
Object
href
:
"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=hello&type=track&offset=0&limit=20"
items
:
Array(20)
limit
:
20
next
:
"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=hello&type=track&offset=20&limit=20"
offset
:
0
previous
:
null
total
:
43551
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
"success"
2
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)` - this is what i get when i print RESULTS to the console

Comment: Sorry, I mean .then((...results)=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(results.slice(0,10), null, 2))})

Comment: @wostex okay, this now seems to print everything out as a very very very long string! Any ideas how I can pick information out of this string that I want - i.e. the uri, name and image link? these are all labelled as the same thing for each song it returns - i.e  "uri":"spotify:artist:4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"